# Eclipse Node Debugger require() exception

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js

I am using windows machine with the latest eclipse.
I followed the instructions over https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger.
On the command line I execute `node --debug-brk server.js`. When I run eclipse debugger, it connects to the node. The first line in my code is `require()`, and when the debugger visits this line, it throws an exception:

```
line 1: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined.
```

I tried to have a breakpoint after that line, but whenever the debugger starts, it visits the first (`require()`) line.
How can I pass this line, and continue debugging?

Answer (score 0):

quote from https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger

> Note that V8 engine debugger is not behaving very good when it steps over or steps into >require() method (it will crash), so try to set up first breakpoint past the initial module >loading. This will also enable you to set breakpoints in any of those modules as well.

try
    node --debug server.js